# How to check if react component detached

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listener

have a question, how to check if react component detached from its parent components?

Let’s say I have a react component, that is subscribed to any async events: WebSocket, timer.

I just want to not waste computer resources on listener to this event, when react component no more in use, and deallocate react component as well.

Any though?

Comment: Either `componentWillUnmount` or a cleanup callback of `useEffect` hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React provides various methods to keep track of a component's lifecycle. And in your case you need to track if a component has unmounted. So, there are 2 approach for this based on the type of component you are using:

#### Class Component

Use [**componentUnmount**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) lifecycle method.

```js
class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // this method is invoked immediately before a component
    // is unmounted and destroyed. you can perform any necessary 
    // cleanup in this method, such as invalidating
    // timers, canceling network requests,
    // or cleaning up subscriptions
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* ...contents... */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Functional Component

Leverage [**useEffect**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook with [**cleanup**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount).

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // rest of code

    return () => {
      // similar to componentWillUnmount() method, this function
      // would invoke at the time of component's unmount.
    };
  },[]);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ...contents... */}
    </div>
  );
}
```